# Как преобразовать массив строк при помощи функции replace?

Tags: javascript

Массив и замена:

```
ready = ['13,1', '24,2']

for (var i = 0; i < ready.length; i++) {
  var zamena = ready.replace(',', '.');

}
console.log(zamena);
```

Comment: *Как заменить запятую на точку?* Есть магическая функция Replace. См. напр. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: @chupas Приложите данные, которые находятся в data

Comment: Отладчик для чего существует?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
     var dat = [{TimeString:'x1',VarValue:'13,2'},{TimeString:'x2',VarValue:'17,2'}];
       var dat2 = dat.map(function(item) {
       return [item.TimeString,parseFloat((item.VarValue).replace(',','.'))]});
   console.log(dat2);
```

Comment: Мапирование массива объектов с заменой запятой на точку в строке при помощи функции `replace`

Answer (score 3):

Простой пример:

```js
const stroka = '44,18403';

const chisloSTochkoy = Number(stroka.replace(',', '.'));

console.log(`${typeof stroka}=${stroka}`, `${typeof chisloSTochkoy}=${chisloSTochkoy}`);
```